# Correct way to use SCOPE_IDENTITY()?

Tags: undefined, php, scope-identity

I have 2 separate forms. The first form handler determines if the second form is needed. Each form populates a separate database table. I need to be able to link corresponding rows later. I am trying to do so by calling `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` after the first form and setting it to a variable to be used as the id in the second form.

I hope that made sense. Here's my code:

```
 $iquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pending (date, ip) VALUES('".$_POST['date']."', '".$_POST['ip']."')");
$asdf = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
echo $asdf;
```

Which give gives me this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function scope_identity() in
>   /public_html/test/index.php on line 138

What is the correct way to do this? keep in mind I need the result to be set as a variable.

Comment: FYI, SCOPE_IDENTITY() is not a PHP or MySQL function, it's a SQL-Server function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysql_insert_id()`:

```
$asdf = mysql_insert_id();
```

or in PDO (which I'm advising you to move, [here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is a nice tutorial):

```
$asdf = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: i was sure that would work, sounded so promising but instead i got this `mysql_insert_id(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource`

Comment: lorga nevermind, i removed $iquery from the parenthesis and it's working brilliantly, thank you!